# Creating anonymous class as custom key in dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, anonymous-class

While using dictionary, i always override GetHashCode and Equals ( or provide a custom comparer to the dictionary).

What happens behind the covers when i create an anonymous class as key?

Sample Code....

```
 var groups=(from item in items
                 group item by new { item.ClientId, item.CustodianId, item.CurrencyId }
                   into g
                   select new {
                     Key=g.Key,                     
                     Sum=g.Sum(x => x.Cash)
                   }).ToDictionary(item=>item.Key,item=>item.Sum);
```

This code gives me the expected result, but i am not providing GetHashCode and Equals method for the anonymous class.
Shouldn't this code fail to group my items on the basis of items in anonymous class??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope - the anonymous class automatically generates appropriate Equals/GetHashCode implementations.

From the C# language spec, section 7.5.10.6:

> The Equals and GetHashcode methods on
>   anonymous types override the methods
>   inherited from object, and are defined
>   in terms of the Equals and GetHashcode
>   of the properties, so that two
>   instances of the same anonymous type
>   are equal if and only if all their
>   properties are equal.